# Android how to sort images by name in grid view and list view

Tags: android

Please any one tell me How to sort Images by name in List view and grid view.
I have Country_images and Country_names.Am sorting by Country_name but,sorting can be done to country_names only.please any one help how to sort images by name.

// Main Activity

```
        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
            public RelativeLayout mainLayout;
            View gridView,listView;
            CountryAdapterList customListAdapter;
            CountryAdapter cutomArrayAdapter;
            public int swithNo=0;
            public String[] country_Names;
            public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
            public int[] country_Images = {R.drawable.banglades, R.drawable.bangladesh,
                    R.drawable.brazi, R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.chin,
                    R.drawable.china, R.drawable.indi, R.drawable.india,
                    R.drawable.indonesi, R.drawable.indonesia, R.drawable.japa,
                    R.drawable.japan, R.drawable.nigeri, R.drawable.nigeria,
                    R.drawable.pakista, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.russi,
                    R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.unitedstate,
                    R.drawable.unitedstates };
            public String[] country_Name_Sort = { "Bangladesh A", "Pakistan",
                    "Brazil A", "Brazil", "China A","Bangladesh", "China", "India A", "India",
                    "Indonesia A", "Russia","Indonesia", "Japan A", "Japan", "Nigeria A",
                    "Nigeria", "Pakistan A",  "Russia A", 
                    "UnitesStates A", "UnitesStates" };
            public float[] country_Image_size = {1.36f , 1.36f, 4.12f, 4.12f, 1.47f,
                    1.47f, 1.79f, 1.79f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 1.50f, 1.50f, 0.285f, 0.285f,
                    1.85f, 1.85f, 0.330f, 0.330f, 3.42f, 3.42f };


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                // Creating a new RelativeLayout
                 relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
                customListAdapter = new CountryAdapterList(getApplicationContext(),
                        country_Name_Sort, country_Image_size, country_Images);
                 cutomArrayAdapter=new CountryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), country_Name_Sort, country_Image_size, country_Images);
                // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
                // In this case I want to fill its parent
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                gridView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_deatails_grid,
                        null);
                listView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main_listview,
                        null);
                setViewUpdate(swithNo);

                ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) gridView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryDetailsScreen.class);

                        i.putExtra("Position", position);
                        i.putExtra("Country_Name", country_Name_Sort);
                        i.putExtra("Country_image", country_Images);
                        i.putExtra("Country_Image_size", country_Image_size);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
                ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) listView).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryDetailsScreen.class);
                        i.putExtra("Position", position);
                        i.putExtra("Country_Name", country_Name_Sort);
                        i.putExtra("Country_image", country_Images);
                        i.putExtra("Country_Image_size", country_Image_size);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                });
            }
            private void sortAscending () {
                List<String> sortedMonthsList = Arrays.asList(country_Name_Sort);
                Collections.sort(sortedMonthsList);
                country_Name_Sort = (String[]) sortedMonthsList.toArray();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                menu.add(1, 1, 0, "Grid View");
                menu.add(1, 2, 1, "List View");
                menu.add(2, 3, 2, "Sort By Name");
                menu.add(2, 4, 3, "Sort By Size");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1:
                    Log.d("SwithNo", "One");
                    swithNo=0;
                    setViewUpdate(swithNo);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d("SwithNo", "Two");
                    swithNo=1;
                    setViewUpdate(swithNo);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d("SwithNo", "Three");
                    sortAscending();
                    for(int i=0;i<country_Name_Sort.length;i++)
                    {
                        Log.e("Assending    ", " "+country_Name_Sort[i]);
                    }
                    ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                    listView.invalidate();
                    setViewUpdate(swithNo);

                    break;
                case 4 : Log.d("Switch", "Four");
                }

                return true;
            }
            public void setViewUpdate(int k)
            {
                ((GridView) gridView).setAdapter(cutomArrayAdapter);
                ((ListView) listView).setAdapter(customListAdapter);
                relativeLayout.removeAllViews();
                if(k==0)
                {
                    relativeLayout.addView(gridView);
                }
                else
                {
                    relativeLayout.addView(listView);
                }

                setContentView(relativeLayout);

            }

        }

        class Country {
            int imageId;
            String countryName;

            Country(int imageId, String countyName) {
                this.imageId = imageId;
                this.countryName = countyName;
            }
        }

        class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            ArrayList<Country> list;
            Context context;
            String[] country_Name_Sort;

            CountryAdapter(Context context,String[] country_Name_Sort,float[] country_Image_size,int[] country_Images) {
                this.context = context;
                this.country_Name_Sort=country_Name_Sort;
                list = new ArrayList<Country>();
                /*Resources resource = context.getResources();
                String[] country_Names = resource.getStringArray(R.array.coutry_names);*/
                for (int i = 0; i < country_Name_Sort.length; i++) {
                    Country country = new Country(country_Images[i], country_Name_Sort[i]);
                    list.add(country);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return list.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            class ViewHolder {
                ImageView county_Image;
                TextView country_Name;

                ViewHolder(View v) {
                    county_Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    country_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                View row = convertView;
                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
                    row.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                }
                Country cntry = list.get(position);
                viewHolder.county_Image.setImageResource(cntry.imageId);
                viewHolder.country_Name.setText(cntry.countryName);

                return row;
            }
        }
            class CountryAdapterList extends BaseAdapter {
                ArrayList<Country> list;
                Context context;
                String[] country_Name_Sort;
                int[] country_Images;

                CountryAdapterList(Context context,String[] country_Name_Sort,float[] country_Image_size,int[] country_Images) {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.country_Name_Sort=country_Name_Sort;
                    this.country_Images=country_Images;
                    list = new ArrayList<Country>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < country_Name_Sort.length; i++) {
                        Country country = new Country(country_Images[i], country_Name_Sort[i]);
                        list.add(country);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return list.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return list.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return position;
                }

                class ViewHolder {
                    ImageView county_Image;
                    TextView country_Name;

                    ViewHolder(View v) {
                        county_Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewList);
                        country_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.countryNameList);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    View row = convertView;
                    if (row == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_item_listview, parent, false);
                        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);
                        row.setTag(viewHolder);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
                    }
                    Country cntry = list.get(position);
                    viewHolder.county_Image.setImageResource(cntry.imageId);
                    viewHolder.country_Name.setText(cntry.countryName);

                    return row;
                }
            }
```

Comment: if it is arraylist use Collections.sort function

Comment: Show your code for help

Comment: Hi Vishwa and Nair,Sharing my code above please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to sort your `country_Images`:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> names = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i< country_Images.length; i++) {
  names.put(getResources().getResourceEntryName(country_Images[i]), country_Images[i]);
}
int i = 0;
int[] sortedCountryImages = new int[country_Images.length]; 
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : names.entrySet()) {
  sortedCountryImages[i] = entry.getValue();
  i++;
}
country_Images = sortedCountryImages;
```

But beware that the order of `country_Images` after sorted maybe doesn't match with your order in `country_Image_size`